# Update SQL Server database schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is an old SQL Server database which needed to be upgraded to much improved version of database schema. Mostly new columns have been added to existing tables. It is necessary to keep original data in the old database. It there any easy way to upgrade the schema than compacting and updating table by table manually?

Comment: try to "alter" as many fields as possible. then delete the old fields and add the new ones. other solution: create a new table and write a php script witch copies the old datas in the new table.

Comment: [There are many solutions to this that prevent you from re-inventing the wheel](http://madelinebertrand.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Adept SQL](http://www.adeptsql.com/) in the past with a lot of success. It will compare the databases for you, and even generate a script to bring one database up the other. It is not a free product, but you can use it for a trial (with most features, I believe.) If this is a one-time operation, it'll be just what you need.

In the interest of full disclosure, we liked the product so much that we did end up purchasing it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it and I will post here the feedback.